# How to use onSavedInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState for imageview, progressbar and button in Kotlin?

Tags: android

In `layout.xml` file contains a `TextView`, `ImageView` and `Progressbar` with id of `tv_text`, `iv_image` and `pb_progressbar` respectively. While rotating the screen the data is lost, how to restore their state upon screen rotation?

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    outState.putString("question", tv_text.text.toString())
    outState.putString("image", iv_image.toString())
}

override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
    val question = savedInstanceState.getString("question")
    tv_text.text = question
    val image = savedInstanceState.getString("image")
    iv_image.toString() = image
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android, when configuration changes, the state of [ProgressBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar) is saved/restored automatically, so you need to save/restore state of `TextView` and `ImageView`.

**Solution**

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)

    // Save state of TextView
    val question = tv_text.text.toString()
    outState.putString("question", question)

    // Save state of ImageView
    val image = iv_image.drawable.toBitmap(iv_image.width,
            iv_image.height,
            Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
    outState.putParcelable("image", image)
}

override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)

    // Restore the state of TextView
    tv_text.text = savedInstanceState.getString("question")

    // Restore the state of ImageView
    iv_image.setImageBitmap(savedInstanceState.getParcelable("image"))
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this great help . Appreciate alot.

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your activity in  manifest

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

This way your Activity wont be restarted automatically

Comment: This does not answer the question, its just pointing out a way around it.